# Mailchimp: Get random member info

Tags: php, mailchimp, memberinfo

This is my first time using the MailChimp API, I've been looking at some examples and trying to figure out this on my own but I can't seem to be able to get what I need.

I only have one list on my account and I'm trying to run a contest where I choose one random winner from the list. So far I've managed to retrieve the total number of members on the list, and from that I have generated a random number to be used as the 'winner'. Now I need to find the member from the list located in that position from the list members array, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

This is what I have so far:

```
include "Mailchimp.php";

/* Load member count */
function mcg_mc_sub_count() {
    $MailChimp = new MailChimp('*****');
    $list = $MailChimp->call('lists/list');
    $total_members .= $list[data][0][stats][member_count];
    return number_format($total_members);
}   

/* Generate random number */
function mcg_mc_random_number() {
    $total_members = mcg_mc_sub_count();
    $random_number = rand(1, $total_members);
    return $random_number;
}
```

I think at this point I should be using `$MailChimp->call('lists/member-info');` but since I only have a random position and not a member id/email, I'm not sure which parameters to use or how to go about it.

Any help is appreciated figuring this method out or through a different way, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic is correct.
MailChimp does not provide an API for random member, but you can get list and create randon function in the array.

Example:

> Start by use-ing the class and creating an instance with your API key

```
use \DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;
$MailChimp = new MailChimp('abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123-us1');
```

> Then, list all the mailing lists (with a get on the lists method)

```
$result = $MailChimp->get('lists');
print_r($result);
```

So, with the list, you can call the members and put in the array. Then you can use some function to get a random value in the array.

```
$input = array("Member 1", "Member 2", "Member 3", "Member 4", "Member 5");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 1);
echo $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
```

Refs:

- [MailChimp API](https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api)
- [PHP array_rand](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-rand.php)

Answer (score 0):

First, it's worth noting that you're using a version of the MailChimp API that is going to [go away at the end of the year](https://devs.mailchimp.com/blog/sunsetting-previous-mailchimp-api-versions/). Just in case this is a one-time script, here's the way to do this in v2.0 that doesn't require downloading your entire list (the same concept will work in v3 with some slight alterations):

Once you have the number of people on the list, go ahead and generate your random number. Then, use the [lists/members endpoint](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/members.php) with the `start` parameter equal to one less than your random number and the `limit` parameter equal to 1.

That should return the exact subscriber you're looking for without requiring you to download the entire list.